# Kafka-spark stream works not in Jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm running several container, Kafka, spark and zookeeper. I pushed data to a Kafka topic (Kafka works and is processing data) and connected spark with this topic, but if I use "KafkaUtils.createDirectStream" Jupiter gives no output. can you please help me?
the docker containers are from [Lambda architecture](https://github.com/apssouza22/lambda-arch)

```
# # Kafka/ pyspark streaming

#Kafka retrieve topics

import sys

from kafka import KafkaClient

client = KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

future = client.cluster.request_update()
client.poll(future=future)

metadata = client.cluster
print(metadata.topics())

#Import libraries to load csv data on topic 'test'

from kafka import KafkaProducer

import logging
from json import dumps, loads
import csv
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#load csv data into kafka topic 'test

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', value_serializer=lambda 
   K:dumps(K).encode('utf-8'))

with open('/Users/karsten/Desktop/Datensets/divvy_data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for messages in reader:
        producer.send('test', messages)
        producer.flush()

import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark


def spark_context_creator():
    conf = SparkConf()
    #set name for our app
    conf.setAppName('divvy_test')
    #the master url to connect
    conf.setMaster('spark://spark-master:7077')
    sc = None
    try:
        sc.stop()
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    except:
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    return sc

sc = spark_context_creator()

    
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,1)


kafkastream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, 'zookeeper:2181', 'my-created-consumer-group', {'test':1})
#extract json data from tupil
data = kafkastream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])).pprint()
print(type(data))
rdd = scc.parallelize(data)
print(type(rdd))
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()


print(rdd)
```

Comment: `localhost` refers to the Jupyter container, not the Kafka broker.... Otherwise, if this runs on the host, then `zookeeper` and `spark-master` are not resolvable hostnames

Comment: thanks for your answer. the jupyter notebook runs not in a container, it runs on localhost. kafka is running in a docker container and usually I should access them over localhost:9092 because I configured KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092' in the compose file. But it doesn't work. In the compose file, I configured spark as follow .. SPARK_DRIVER_HOST=192.168.1.5, but how can I access the master?

Comment: Same issue, then. Spark is actually running the code. That's in a container, so it won't be able to connect to localhost to find Kafka. And as I said, zookeeper and spark-master are unknown DNS names to your host

Comment: Do you actually need Spark, though? You've already got a Python Kafka library that can consume your data

Comment: is there a solution for this? I must be able to access kafka in the container somehow with pyspark from jupyter?

Comment: Well, did you try using `spark://localhost:7077` and `localhost:2181` (although, you shouldn't be using Zookeeper)?